# One image per overlay?

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays

I would that the images would appeared for each overlay. Eg, in `overlay 1` I have `img1.pdf`, in `overlay 2` I have `img2.pdf`, and in `overlay 3` I have `img3.pdf`. How I do this?

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (img1) {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{img1.pdf}};
    \pause
    \node (img2) {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{img2.pdf}};
    \pause
    \node (img3) {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{img3.pdf}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Do yo want to get those three images in the same slide or in different but subsequent slides? I have not clear the question, could you explain yourself better and add a complete MWE for your question?

Comment: I made an edit to this question, hope it's appropriate, feel free to roll back if not

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`\node` (as well as all TikZ paths) is overlay-aware so you can use

```
\node<overlay spec.> [options] {contents};
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node<1> (img1) {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node<2> (img2) {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
    \node<3> (img3) {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

With your numbering schema you can use a loop:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \Value in {1,2,3}
      \node<\Value> (img\Value) {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{img\Value}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please take look http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281375/inspired-beautiful-box-from-indesign#281400

Comment: Congrats on passing the 300K mark!!!!

Answer (score 20):

I like using `tikz` too, but in this particular case it may not be necessary :)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics<1>[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics<2>[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \includegraphics<3>[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]